# Can an agora project handle multiple live broadcast rooms?

Tags: video-streaming, live-streaming, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

The context is to create a live streaming android app using Agora services. I am unsure if a single agora project can handle all the live stream rooms. According to the agora tutorial, I used the temporary token which required the channel name and app id.

I am wondering if multiple broadcasters want to create channels with different names, is agora able to run multiple rooms simultaneously? How do I do so using the temporary token?

If yes, will the rooms have different tokens?

Will there be any drastic changes if I proceed to use the app certificate to produce the token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can definitely join multiple channels using Agora. Here is the documents for joining multiple channels: https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/multiple_channel_android?platform=Android. You can use the token generator to generate the token from the server and it is not hard to do. You can see the instruction here: https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/token_server_cpp?platform=CPP.